# Rails: devise mails "sent" according to log but not receiving any in my gmail inbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise

I have checked if the email has being filtered as spam, but the spam folder does not contain it.

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'example.com' }
# ActionMailer Config
# Setup for production - deliveries, no errors raised
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "example.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
config.mailer_sender = 'example@gmail.com'
```

**Heroku logs:**

```
2016-06-03T10:42:41.963581+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to ****@gmail.com (1222.9ms)
```

I also tried it with development, but I got to the same result. Somehow it is sending but it is never arriving.

Who can help me to solve the issue?

Comment: does your mailer specify an address that the email should be received by?

Comment: @stephenmurdoch Yes it does: **config.mailer_sender = 'example@gmail.com'**. I will add it to my question for clarification.

Comment: Can you run `env` or `printenv` from the command line on your localhost? I wonder if your environment variable is being overwritten somewhere.

Comment: Somehow the mailer is working for production today. I did not change the code, but now I am receiving the actual confirmation email.

Answer (score 2):

In your configured  Gmail account:

1. Go to  <kbd>Account Settings</kbd> Than
2. Go to <kbd>Sign-in & security</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Connected apps & sites</kbd>
3. At last in <kbd>Allow less secure apps</kbd> ... Check it.

My Development Envionment Setting For Send Mail

development.rb =>

```
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

=> In initializers => create file as mail_setup.rb, paste this config

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  # :domain               => "http://localhost:8082.com",
  :user_name            => "mukesh.sharma@skilrock.com",
  :password             => "**************",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: I checkout the configuration of the gmail account that I use to send emails. The allow less secure apps status is "on". But when I try to sign up again, the gmail account does not send a confirmation mail to the user's gmail.

Comment: After I create the file mail_setup.rb I get an error after trying to sign up: **end of file reached**. So I used **spring stop** and tried again. Now different error: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at. I am getting confused :(.

Comment: I also see that my gmail account is saying: 
detected unusual activity. Which is odd because the status for allow less secure apps is on

Comment: it's not a big problem...n always keep a test account on gmail  to  use on apps for testing :)

Comment: Check your username and password of gamil in mail_setup.rb  once

Comment: username and password are correct. When I see the log(rails s) its trying to send the confirmation mail, but then it is doing a rollback and coming with that error. And when I test it for production, it doesn't give me any error and the heroku log is saying that the email is sent.

Comment: I do not know how, but the devise mailer is working for production... while I did not change a thing. For development is is still not working, but not sure if I should care now. :P